# Web deploy 401. IIS and apppool?

Tags: authentication, iis, microsoft-web-deploy

Web deploy works when I publish from visual studio but fails when I call msdeploy.exe. The failure is 401 unauthorized but both ways use the same iis account to login. Both ways go via WMSVC.

This is the web deploy command

```
msdeploy.exe -source:package='MyZip.Api.zip' -dest:auto,computerName='https://94.236.2.239/MSDeploy.axd?site=MySitei',userName=myusername,password=mypassowrd,authtype=basic,includeAcls=false  -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -setParamFile:"MySetParameters.xml" -allowUntrusted
```

On the target server I can see two security log failure

> The computer attempted to validate the credentials for an account.
>
> Authentication Package:   MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0 Logon
>   Account:  MyIISAccount Source Workstation:    MyServer Error
>   Code: 0xC0000064

The second error

> An account failed to log on.
>
> Subject:  Security ID:        IIS APPPOOL.NET v4.5   Account Name:       .NET
>   v4.5  Account Domain:     IIS APPPOOL     Logon ID:       0x52A7CD9
>
> Logon Type:           8
>
> Account For Which Logon Failed:   Security ID:        NULL SID    Account
>   Name:     Myiisacount     Account Domain:     myserver
>
> Failure Information:  Failure Reason:     Unknown user name or bad
>   password.     Status:         0xC000006D  Sub Status:     0xC0000064
>
> Process Information:  Caller Process ID:  0x1900  Caller Process
>   Name: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
>
> Network Information:  Workstation Name:   myserver    Source Network
>   Address:  myip    Source Port:        50384
>
> Detailed Authentication Information:  Logon Process:      Advapi
>     Authentication Package: Negotiate   Transited Services: -   Package
>   Name (NTLM only): -   Key Length:     0

Answer (score 0):

NULL SID probably means that the computer couldn't locate the account at all (not that the password is bad). Double-check the account spelling and try to localize the account: if it's a local account on computer COMPUTERNAME try `COMPUTERNAME\ACCOUNT` and if it's a domain account (e.g. on domain CONTOSO), try `CONTOSO\ACCOUNT` or the FQDN format `account@contoso.com` for the contoso.com domain.

You may also want to try the `-AuthType='NTLM'` from the command prompt.